# naming ids using Razor C# syntax

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a for loop in my razor document:

```
@for(var i = 0; i < Model.Content.Cars; i++)
{
    <p id = "car@i"> This is a car. </p>
}
```

I am trying to get something like this:

```
<p id = "car1"> This is a car. </p>

<p id = "car2"> This is a car. </p>

<p id = "car3"> This is a car. </p>

<p id = "car4"> This is a car. </p>
```

How do I achieve this effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put i in ()

```
    <p id = "car@(i)"> This is a car. </p>
```